# appsecret_proof that spans multiple apps - kind of like token_for_business

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Update: I need more investigation to be able to ask.

I have a server that handles all my requests to Facebook on behalf of mobile clients. To secure the access_token from the Facebook user, Facebook recommends using `appsecret_proof`. I have more then one app.

Question: is it possible to get a `appsecret_proof` that covers all apps. Kind of like token_for_business is covering ids?

Update: I need more investigation to be able to ask.

Answer (score 1):

`appsecret_proof` includes the App Secret, so of course you need a new `appsecret_proof` for every single App. Not sure why you would try using the same one for different Apps though, `token_for_business` is for something completely different: to identify a User between different Apps.